# Code point \u0008 is not a valid character in XML in Perl script

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to grep the errors from a console log and forming a XML using Perl, For some files I am getting  error as "Code point \u0008 is not a valid character in XML at /codepath/getErrors.pl line 498".

Browsing for \u0008 speaks about backspace chars, but I'm not sure how to remove this from the string/text.

It will be great if you could help me in removing this kind of control characters while reading the console log, so that XML formation runs without any errors.

Much Appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backspaces are indeed no [valid character in an XML file](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets). This indicates the tool producing the “XML” is broken in some way. If possible, apply a fix there.

If it really has to be, you can filter out backspaces from the file like

```
$ perl -pe's/\x08//g' <brokenfile.not-xml >fixedfile.still-not-xml
```

If your file includes other control characters, you can extend the regex to whole ranges:

```
#filtering forbidden control characters in the ASCII range
$ perl -pe's/[\x00-\x08\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F]//g' <brokenfile.not-xml >fixedfile.still-not-xml
```

Legal XML characters are:

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

But please be aware that your original file *is not* XML, and that whatever library you are using is doing the right thing by throwing an error.

Depending on the data the file (was intended to) represent, filtering out the control codes may change the meaning of that data.

Comment: +1 for "But please be aware that your original file is not XML". This is a point that isn't made often enough. Malformed input is not content of the form that your parser is meant to handle. Some will attempt to, but that doesn't mean that the parsers that throw errors are incorrect, they are doing their job. That said, your other suggestions are good, fix the other tool (generator) or fix the input.

Comment: @amon Would 'perl -pe's/.\x08//g' would give you a file with actual user input?

Comment: @Jim Black, well, it's one step closer. There are other escapes you might encounter, and it might not actually be possible to recreate the XML from some log contents.